# Reading first line from a file in C++

Tags: c++, fopen, fgets

I would like to perform the following actions:

1. Read the first line from a file and store it in a variable `N`.
2. Read the file lines for `0 <= i < N` and store them in a array to sort them later.

NOTE: if `N == 0` then it should exit.

Here is my code:

```
FILE *f = fopen(argv[1], "r");

while (true)
{    
    fgets (mystring , 100 , f);
    cout << mystring;
    fseek(f, 1, SEEK_CUR);
    N = atoi(mystring);    

    if (N == 0)
    {
        cout << "\n Exit";
        exit(0);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        bzero(mystring, sizeof(mystring));
        fgets (mystring , 100 , f);
        fseek(f, 1, SEEK_CUR);
        a[i] = atoi(mystring);
        cout << a[i];
    }
}
```

It reads the first file (which contains `N`) correctly, but then it reads the file as `00000000000` so that the next value of N becomes `0` and it exits the loop.

Here is my input file:

```
10
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
5
3
3
5
1
2
5
5
6
0
```

Could anyone please help me resolving this issue?

Comment: I want to read first line from a file and store it in N and reads the file for i<N and store it in a array to sort it....if N==o then it will exit...it reads the first file (which is the number)correctly but it reads the file as 00000000000 so that the next value of N becomes 0 and exits the loop....any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are you sure the input file contains each value in a separate line? Your example shows that this is one line only. If this is one line only then you read "10" first, and then each time you read 'nothing', and call `atoi( "" )` which is 0.

Comment: What is `a`? What is `mystring`? What is `N`? We need to see how these things are declared. Also, you need to ask a question.

Comment: The fact that you `fseek` past the first character of each line might have something to do with it. Anyway `fseek` is not well-defined for text files.

Comment: N is the first number in the file...mystring is the buffer and a[i] is an array where i store the first N numbers to be sort

Comment: @Grzegorz yes each value is in the separate line...yea what u said is right..how can i overcome this problem..kindly help

Comment: I'm not sure why you are using FILE over fstream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

Remove extra `fseek(f, 1, SEEK_CUR);`

Each `fgets()` reads line including new line.
So the file pointer points at the beginning of the new line.
Your `fseek` moves the pointer to the next character which is a new line character (`\n`).
`atoi()` of an empty string returns 0.

That *will* do help.

Now, there is one small thing that you make correct. If your `mystring` is declared as `char mystring[100]` then in each place you call `fgets`, change your `100` to `sizeof(mystring)`. That is more correct.

I do not understand why you got so many negative points. I am upping your question.

Comment: hey thanks..now it reads the file..but there is a small problem...it takes the value of N correctly but the first number followed by N is always 0.....

Comment: Have you removed both `fseeks` ?

Comment: no the second one only..if i remove the first one am getting all zeroes

Comment: hey thanks ..now i removed both fseek and got the answer

Comment: To make you project better, you can delete `bzero` call as it is not needed. Also, you could add extra test in case wrong number of data has been inserted.